# Conjugate matrices transposed?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If we denote 
$A^*=\left (\overline{A} \right)^T$ ( as in $\overline{A}$ transposed) as the conjugate matrix of $A$ why is the conjugate transposed or why does it have to be?

Comment: "Configure"? What is "configure"? Also, the "conjugate transpose" is sometimes called the "tranjugate".

Comment: Autocorrect sorry

Comment: Obviously(?) if the matrix is purely real, taking conjugates doesn't make any difference, so the "purpose" of doing things this way is clearly for complex matrices.  To take a step back, how do we define the Euclidean norm for a complex vector?  Something about that shines light on the inner product definition for complex vectors (and less directly, on the need for the conjugate in defining $A^*$ the way you've shown here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$A^*$ is called the conjugate transpose, or Hermitian transpose of $A$, but of course you can just have the conjugate of A, which is the conjugate of each of its elements.

Comment: Okay so they both exist but A* is something that's useful in theorems. Thanks!

Comment: That's right, to define an inner product in $\mathbb{C}$ for exemple (for vectors). If it answered your question, please accept the answer!